# System Level Hook or Event needed when a user submits a Post Request from any Web Browser

Tags: c#, http, post, hook

I have looked at using FiddlerCore, but it's very heavy weight for what I need.  i don't want all the packet detail, etc, I just want to know when someone submits a post request.  I also have tried using pcap, but it has dependencies I don't want to tangle with.  Is there any way via .NET or Windows Native framework to tell if someone submits a post request?

Comment: Lol, have I truly reached the realm where even Skeet fears to tread?